# I cannot seem to Archive build on my version of xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, build

There is no option for me to Archive my application in the menu. How do you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are using Xcode 4. In the **Scheme**, select iOS Device. Now in the **Product** menu, you would be able to Archive.

Comment: OMG! I thought I was going crazy.. holy moly... thank you very much kind sir.

Comment: That works. It always helps for me to see it this way: **Menu: Product > Archive** - Thx.